# Canvas Page is blank when viewing in page mode?

Tags: facebook, canvas

Why is it that the apps we developed do not show any content when we are viewing them in Page mode?  When I switch to my personal profile everything shows up, but if I'm in my Business Profile, my canvas page is blank?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7437263/facebook-app-iframe-wont-attempt-to-load-when-logged-in-as-page

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug/desired-behavior of Profile Tab applications while using Facebook as page, status of this can be tracked on http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/141770462584785

**Update:**
Bug is marked as fixes but the fix doesn't really resolve the issue. Currently if you try to visit Application Tab on Page you will be prompted to switch back to use Facebook as user:

> You are using Facebook as PAGE_NAME
>   To access this page, you'll need to switch from using Facebook as your page to using Facebook as yourself.

Comment: as for now application canvas not even requested by Facebook if you logged in as Facebook Page...